# Не запускается файл с tkinter(PYTHON)

Tags: python

Когда запускаю код через IDLE, все работает, но когда пытаюсь через консоль, выдает ошибку:

```
NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined.
```

Comment: Скорее всего у вас установлено два интерпретатора Python, и в одном из них не установлен tkinter. А вообще, добавьте ваш код в вопрос, может с импортом что-то.

Comment: а какое у вас имя скрипта ?

Comment: @insolor два интерпретатора разных версий. В одном `tk`, в другом `Tk`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, в Python2 - Tkinter, в Python3 - tkinter, но класс Tk и там и там одинаково называется. Если было бы дело в версии Python, то ругалось бы на tkinter.

Comment: Хотя если бы tkinter не был установлен, то тоже на него ругалось бы. Так что да, возможно какой-то из файлов tkinter.py назван.

Answer (score 1):

## есть разные причины...

Python 3.x:

```
import tkinter # "t" is lowercase
```

Python 2.x:

```
import Tkinter # "T" is uppercase
```

Install on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

Windows:

> Well I can see two solutions here:
>
> ***1) Follow the [Docs-Tkinter install for Python](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html) ([for Windows](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html#installwin)):***
>
> Tkinter (and, since Python 3.1, ttk) are included with all standard
> Python distributions. It is important that you use a version of Python
> supporting Tk 8.5 or greater, and ttk. We recommend installing the
> "ActivePython" distribution from ActiveState, which includes
> everything you'll need.
>
> In your web browser, go to [Activestate.com](http://www.activestate.com), and follow along the
> links to download the Community Edition of ActivePython for Windows.
> Make sure you're downloading a 3.1 or newer version, not a 2.x
> version.
>
> Run the installer, and follow along. You'll end up with a fresh
> install of ActivePython, located in, e.g. `C:\python32`. From a
> Windows command prompt, or the Start Menu's "Run..." command, you
> should then be able to run a Python shell via:
>
> ```
> % C:\python32\python
> ```
>
> This should give you the Python command prompt. From the prompt, enter
> these two commands:
>
> ```
> >>> import tkinter
> >>> tkinter._test()
> ```
>
> This should pop up a small window; the first line at the top of the
> window should say "This is Tcl/Tk version 8.5"; make sure it is not
> 8.4!
>
> ***2) Uninstall 64-bit Python and install 32 bit Python.***

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044559/how-to-pip-or-easy-install-tkinter-on-windows/20044661#20044661)